# Extracting date and time from html form to use them in a mysql query

Tags: php, html, mysql

User must chose between two dates and a query will return the number of answers that are given by employees

```
<form action="mojaTvrtka.php" method="POST">

    <input datetime="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>"   name="vrijeme" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>">
    <input datetime="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>"    name="vrijeme1" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>">
    <input type='submit' name='postavi' value="Zatraži rz!">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['vrijeme']))
{
    $postavljeno = $_POST['vrijeme'];
}
if(isset($_POST['vrijeme1']))
{
    $postavljeno1 = $_POST['vrijeme1'];
    var_dump($postavljeno1);    
}

if(isset($_POST['postavi']))
    {
        $connect=connectDB();
        $statsQuery ="
SELECT ime
     , prezime
     , COUNT(*) AS broj_odgovora 
  FROM korisnik k
     , zaposlenik z
     , odgovor o
 WHERE k.korisnik_id = z.korisnik_id 
   AND z.zaposlenik_id = o.zaposlenik_id
   AND z.tvrtka_id = '{$_SESSION['tvrtkaId']}' 
   AND o.datum_vrijeme_odgovora BETWEEN '{$postavljeno}' AND '{$postavljeno1}' 
 GROUP 
    BY korisnicko_ime
";

            $statsResult = queryDB($connect,$statsQuery);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($statsResult) > 0)
            {

        echo "<h2> Popis odgovora </h2>";
        echo "<table border ='1'>";
        echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Ime i prezime </th>";
        echo "<th>Odgovori </th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";
        echo "<tbody>";

                   while(list($ime,$prezime,$broj_odgovora)=mysqli_fetch_row($statsResult))
                {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$ime." ".$prezime."</a></td>";
                    echo "<td>".$broj_odgovora."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                echo "</tbody>";
                echo "</table>";


                }
                else 
                {
                    echo"Nema rezultata za traženo razdoblje!";
                }
        }
    disconnectDB($connect);
?>
```

Date and time input must be "2019-11-01 00:00:00" and thats mysql datetime value. Above code works without any errors and when I var_dump($postavljeno1) the correct format is applaied but nothing happens.

Comment: Take the `$statsQuery`. Echo it out, copy and run it in MySQL. Does the SQL work? Just no results? Debug it.

Comment: Maybe the query returns no rows?

Comment: You want to read about [SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: @ficuscr Yes query works when I run it in xampp

Comment: Ok funny thing I was loged in as a wrong user so everything is fine sorry and thank you.

Comment: Well if you execute the same SQL in both places you should get the same result. So the SQL isn't the issue. We can assume then your code is at fault. What errors are you getting?

Comment: Glad you figure it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($inputdate))." 00:00:00";
```